# ado.net entity data model not using the entity names correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to add an existing database to my project, but it doesn't respect the schemas in.
On my project I do:

Add new file -> data -> ado.net entity data model -> EF designer from database -> .... -> and I select the tables I want.

The tables look like this: [Image from sql manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm2OE.png)

And they are imported like this: [Image from visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eX1M.png)

Is there any way to make EF generate entity data model classess with naming structure like [schema.name], e.g., Stock.Equis?

Comment: Do you want `Stock` to be part of the class name, or part of the namespace?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Class name.

Answer (score 0):

**C# does not allow '.' character in class names so the naming structure that you are looking for is not possible.**

If you still want to have some kind identifier in class names for schema then you might be able to find work arounds but I would suggest not to do so because if you make this kind of customization here then to adapt to this customization you will have to develop several work arounds with many future code as your project grows. This kind of customization may also make code look inconsistent, cause readers difficulty in understanding the code because this convention has been followed by Entity Framework for over a decade now, cause maintenance problems and might also violate C# best practices. Therefore I suggest, play along and stick with the default implementation. I personally always stick with default implementations and I have never faced any complications.

Following is a short article on working with Schema Names in Entity Framework. This may be helpful to get the idea on how to link Schema Name with Entity Data Model classes. This article is for Code-First approach but you should be able to grasp the concept for Database-First approach as well.

https://www.itprotoday.com/development-techniques-and-management/working-schema-names-entity-framework-code-first-design

Answer (score 0):

You must to use an annotation for this.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("StudentMaster")]
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

Reference: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/table-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx